# alternate lines printed during I/O in C

Tags: c, file, io, fgets, scanf

I am trying to change the text format of a text file using C. 
Following is the code that I have tried. The problem with the output is that the code skips every second line of the text file.

Following is the file I am trying to format.

```
Protein
26709
    1MET      N    1  1.826  3.097  3.556 -0.457  0.365 -0.163
    1MET      H    2  1.769  3.168  3.512 -0.606 -0.305 -1.071
    1MET     H2    3  1.781  3.006  3.565  0.271  0.041  0.264
    1MET     H3    4  1.857  3.125  3.649  1.251 -2.295  0.144
    1MET     CA    5  1.948  3.077  3.475 -0.538 -0.282 -0.098
    1MET     HA    6  1.987  2.977  3.504 -2.137 -0.912 -0.071
    1MET     CB    7  1.914  3.075  3.321  0.389 -0.161 -0.089
    1MET    HB2    8  1.848  2.987  3.306 -0.909  0.569  1.297
    1MET    HB3    9  1.869  3.176  3.311 -1.707 -1.073 -0.224
    1MET     CG   10  2.034  3.050  3.220  0.171  0.344 -0.271
```

And I get the output as :

```
Protein

26709

   1MET       H     2   1.769   3.168   3.512  -0.606  -0.305  -1.071
   1MET      H3     4   1.857   3.125   3.649   1.251  -2.295   0.144
   1MET      HA     6   1.987   2.977   3.504  -2.137  -0.912  -0.071
   1MET     HB2     8   1.848   2.987   3.306  -0.909   0.569   1.297
   1MET      CG    10   2.034   3.050   3.220   0.171   0.344  -0.271
   1MET     HG3    12   2.017   2.974   3.140   2.388   1.184  -1.570
   1MET      CE    14   2.245   3.113   3.036   0.088  -0.370   0.744
   1MET     HE2    16   2.311   3.190   2.990  -0.737  -0.490  -0.665
   1MET       C    18   2.043   3.195   3.504  -0.052  -0.237  -0.714
```

Following is the code that I have tried :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[200],res[10],atm[10],atmNum[10],x[10],y[10],z[10],vx[10],vy[10],vz[10];
    if (argc<2){
        printf("SYTEM ABORT ! \n Provide the input GRO file");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(fgets(buff,200,fp)!=NULL){
        if (strlen(buff) > 10) {
            fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",res,atm,atmNum,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
            if (strcmp(atm,"Na")){
                printf("%7s %7s %5s %7s %7s %7s %7s %7s %7s",res,atm,atmNum,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
            }
            else
                printf("%8s %7s %5s %7s %7s %7s %7s %7s %7s",res,atm,atmNum,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
        }
        else
            printf("%s",buff);

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

As it can be seen from the output file the first line is skipped, I guess that is due to the usage of `fgets` in `while` loop. But after that it prints every alternate lines.

Comment: In the positive (length > 10) case of your `if`-block, I'm pretty sure you should be using `sscanf` and the buffer you just pulled with `fgets` as the data source rather than than throwing it out and using `fscanf` to get the next line. Frankly you should also be checking the result of your `scanf` to ensure all the parameters you're about to use were actually populated. Don't assume anything; assumption is the mother of all...

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot, that was an easy fix.

Answer (score 3):

But you use fgets() and then fscanf() here:

```
while(fgets(buff,200,fp)!=NULL)  
  if (strlen(buff) > 10) {
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",res,atm,atmNum,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz);
```

so you will read one line with fgets() and you will read the next line with fscanf, resulting in skipping the line, as you say.

---

As WhozCraig said, you should use [sscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/), instead of [fscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/).

Comment: Yes, thats true but I didn't know that it will also skip every alternate line. But yes it runs in a while loop. That makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome @PythonNoob, you made a good question, that's why we were able to help. ;)